# Detecting "enter" keyup event on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox

I've got a checkbox called 'beveiligdj'.
It looks like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="beveiligdj" name="beveiligdj" value="j">Ja</label>
```

When you select it (by keyboard) and then press enter, it should go to the `#beveiligdn` input (also a checkbox) But it does not!

```
   $('#beveiligdj').keyup(function(event) {

    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        checked = $('#beveiligdj').is(':checked');

        if(checked) {
            $('#beveiligdn').focus();
        }
    }

   });
```

It just goes to the following field. 
How can I fix that?

Comment: Should it also *check* the checkbox (because `Enter` does not do this) or just move to the next input?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the old trick with the setting of the focus inside of `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#beveiligdn').focus();
},100);
```

You can even try to use 0 instead if 100.